# Call browser plugin from javascript

Tags: javascript, plugins, browser-extension, native-methods

I want to perform the following task:

1. Call a browser plugin from javascript.
2. In turn the plugin will call C/C++ (Native code present on client machine).

Moreover, I would like to know whether the aforementioned task is possible or not. If yes, how it can be done

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the browser!

Since the plugin **can** communicate with the website, that part is not a problem!
The tricky part is to execute C/C++ code from the browser plugin. Look [here for google chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client)

So first u need your browser plugin. then u simple can inject a JS callback into the webpage where u wanna use your plugin. U can use this callback from the website then.

Im not sure what exaclty u wanna do with C/C++! If u want to break out of the Sandbox u need another Process running on your client machine. Then u can communicate with that process to execute additional code.